# Is a Bachelor's sufficient to claim being an "engineer" in countries with Engineer's degrees?

Tags: etiquette, degree, titles

Here in Peru, a Bachelor's degree recipient can do an additional thesis to earn an [Engineer's degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineer%27s_degree) to be recognized as an engineer.

Some Bachelor's degree holders have been calling themselves engineers on the basis of their undergraduate coursework and Bachelor's thesis.  This seems unfair to those who have invested the additional time, effort, and money necessary to earn their Engineer's degree.

**Question:**  Is it appropriate for a Bachelor's degree holder to refer to themself as an "*engineer*" without having earned an Engineer's degree in a country like Peru?

Comment: This is both a highly opinion based question and very specific to the culture of Peru. I don't think it is likely that you are going to get useful responses.

Comment: In some places use of the title "engineer" is regulated by law. But if not, then it seems to be a meaningless title. People employing such others need to take it into account, of course.

Comment: I edited the question a bit to clarify the wording.  However, you might be interested in modifying it a bit -- for example, you could ask how to deal with Bachelor's degree holders calling themselves engineers, or you might ask if there're university regulations prohibiting that practice, etc..

Comment: Nicole, read carefully the link, to be considered an engineer you need both bachellor and engineer degree.

Comment: @Buffy I think in quite a few places being allowed to call yourself an “engineer” is regulated by law - you don’t want a bridge falling down and killing people because the guy who designed it didn’t know what they were doing. I think that this question would be best rephrased as “How do engineering professional organisations in nations where postgraduate engineering degrees are required handle engineers from nations where only bachelors degrees are required?”

Comment: @SolarMike I disagree that this question is opinion-based; it should be answerable by consulting the regulations/bylaws of engineering professional organisations like Engineers Australia.

Answer (score 3):

Ignore it, move on. I'm guessing you probably have better things to worry about than that.

If you are in a hiring position, looking for an engineer, that distinction would make a difference. Otherwise, you would just be pedantically annoying, without any real effect.

ps: In Brazil, by law, every lawyer gets the right to be called 'doctor' after graduation (no MS, no PhD, nothing). It's ridiculous and anyone caring about it is wasting time.